# Add additional suggestion at top of AutoCompleteText suggestions

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I want to make the first suggested line for every AutoCompleteTextView be what the user has currently typed, similar to how google search bar works in smartphones. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

you have to store the value that user typed in sqlite or shared preferences first.
Then you can filter the value based on user's new search...

Take a look at this link: it uses a web service to load data
http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/

Comment: Wait... so I would have to update the variable and set the adapter (notifydatasetchanged is not working for me) everytime the user types a letter?, wouldn't that be too much work to proccess?

Comment: you can show suggestion even when no letter is typed.. AutoCompleteTextView text;
.....
.....
text.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
      text.showDropDown();
      return false;
   }
});